# Making bots that navigate the web

Tags: java, bots

I've always wanted to automate some things like in browser games, such as OGame, or Facebook poking. I could use the java.awt.Robot class, which is the only solution I've found out there, but that isn't necessarily going to pick things up every time and it takes over your computer.

So what I want to do is make a bot that will do things like sign into websites and keep the login cookies, so that it can actually access things, press buttons, fill forms, etc.

So how can this be done?

(I'm not looking for a spider... I've already made something like that that rips Javadocs)

Thanks in advance!
~Somanayr

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [WebHarvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/index.php), pretty neat!

It has an autoexecutable JAR with a good interface to create scripts (XML files), once the script is good just put it in the classpath and use the API to *execute* it whenever you want.

Of course it can fill forms, keep cookies, etc

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just to check, if I use this I can do things like submit forms, etc?

Comment: Excellent. It looks like you control it with XML, but do I still write the bulk of the logic in Java?

Comment: You control the navigation with the XML and you can logic there, of course this is a Java framework so you can use the API however you want

Answer (score 0):

I used selenium drivers, like phantomjs for a headless browser to automate ogame.  It's not perfect and if you'd like to take a look or contribute to the project just let me know.

Selenium is very easy and unlike the java robot class, you don't need to click on actual buttons.  With the java Robot class you'd need to somehow parse the page's content like what sikuli is doing with images, but selenium gives you the page's html which you can use jsoup or even built in selenium functions to read the page.

https://github.com/unsupo/ogame/tree/ogame_2.0